# Laptop won't boot from anything except HDD

Tags: windows, boot

I have a Windows 7 install disc (official,etc), I tried this in a laptop which would not boot to Windows 7, instead getting stuck on "the boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible", the error code being 0xc000000f

I tried putting the disc into the drive and booting from that, but it kept asking me to put a disk in the drive and press any key (the drive span up, then down and then the message appeared), I tried with 3 other different install discs and a live disc of Ubuntu, same result. I then got told that often the CD drive doesn't work.

So on a separate computer I made a bootable USB stick from the install disc. Which worked well when booting on this other computer. But when I put it in the laptop it, and selected a the USB stick from the boot selection menu, it just showed an underscore, pressing any key did nothing.

What causes a laptop (Asus N53J) just to not boot from a USB stick? It supports booting from USB sticks, just literally does nothing when it is selected?

(I can boot to some asus recovery mode by pressing F9, but only learnt of this after about 3 hours)

Comment: Looks to be a ~3 year old model? If so, it *shouldn't* have problems with USB boot like older PCs did. Still, can you check in the BIOS whether options like "Legacy USB support", "Allow booting from removable drives" etc. are enabled?

Comment: Legacy USB support is enabled.

Comment: Since you're attempting to reinstall anyway (and I assume you have your data backed up), does the recovery mode work?

Comment: No it got stuck on 43% and then got stuck on "ERROR" in huge red writing...

Comment: Just "error"? Are you sure the HDD's ok? If it's possible I'd recommend taking the drive out, placing it in a 2.5" USB enclosure, running a full surface test by connecting to another PC and if it passes, back up your data and get rid of all (OS) partitions. Then put it back and see if it boots from USB or not.

Comment: Ok, so it booted to ubuntu on USB stick, where I updated the master boot record, and checked the ntfs file system, which had no problems, and it had no effect on booting to windows.

Comment: Like I said, perhaps a completely clean hard disk's the only way. You can use GParted in Linux for this, if you're willing to try it. (Although before that, have you tried running Win7 setup from USB?)